# What would be webdriver equivalent for selenium IDE command 'assertTextNotPresent'?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-ide

I need some help!

Please find below my selenium IDE code which when converted to webdriver code gives me **// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [isTextPresent]]**

```
<tr>
    <td>assertTextNotPresent</td>
    <td>//*[@id='collapseComment']/div/div/div[2]/label</td>
    <td>Max. 3072 characters</td>
</tr>
```

Basically I want my test to fail if it find the text string '**Max. 3072 characters**' on the page during runtime

I would be grateful if someone can please help me by providing java equivalent of this which i can use.

Cheers
Shan

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I see is that the IDE command of assertTextNotPresent does not accept a target and value. It only needs a target that contains the pattern of the text being searched on. Currently your test asserts that the text of "//*[@id='collapseComment']/div/div/div[2]/label" is not anywhere on the page.

If you use the IDE command of assertNotText it will work correctly. assertNotText requires a locator in the target and a value to compare. When you use IDE to export to Java it will translate assertNotText correctly.

With that in mind, in Java with JUnit 4 the answer is :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
...
WebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='collapseComment']/div/div/div[2]/label"));
assertThat("Max. 3072 characters", is(not(element.getText())));
```

or

```
assert(false, element.getText().contains("Max. 3072 characters"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what assertion/unit testing framework you are using, but this is in C# and NUnit:

```
IWebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
IWebElement element = firefoxDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='collapseComment']/div/div/div[2]/label"));
Assert.IsFalse(element.Text.Contains("Max. 3072 characters"));
```

Comment: I am using testNG with Java.

I would be grateful if you can tell me what would be java equivalent using testNg framework.